# Roll Convention for 7D Index

Tags: swaps, interest-rate-swap

Any specific Roll Convention that I should use for Indexes with 7D tenor like CNY-CNREPOFIX=CFXS-Reuters or USD-SIFMA Municipal Swap Index ? What will be the Calculation Period Frequency or the Payment Frequency for Payment/Accrual calculation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can a reset date be a holiday? The Chinese have a whole week holiday at the start of October. What happens at this time in these instruments?

Answer (score 2):

The CNY 7D swaps have 3M calculation and payment periods. Within those 3M calculation periods the swap will have 7D reset periods. The fixing is -1D prior to the reset date each week and this date can vary it depends on start and end date of swap.

Muni swaps however fix on each Wed effective for Thursday so the weekly reset date is always set on Thursday.